# liquid: dynamically hide placeholder links

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have a YAML file in my `_data` folder that contains a list of links I have in my main nav.

`_data/nav.yml`:

```
main:

  - title: Link A
  - url: "/path/to/linkA"

  - title: Link B
  - url: "/path/to/linkB"

  - title: Link C
  - url: "#"
```

I then use liquid to dynamically generate the links. Here's the relevant portion of my header file.

`_includes/header.html`:

```
<nav class="quick-links">
  {% for item in site.data.nav.main %}
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% if forloop.last == false %} :: {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```

The nav outputs as:

```
Link A :: Link B :: Link C
```

I'd like the output to look like the following

```
Link A :: Link B
```

since `Link C` is a placeholder.

How can I dynamically hide placeholder links, i.e. links with "#" as the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to group correctly nav items in yaml file as:

```
main:
  -
    title: Link A
    url: "/path/to/linkA"
  -
    title: Link B
    url: "/path/to/linkB"
  -
    title: Link C
    url: "#"
```

Then you can avoid the `link c` using the `unless` tag:

```
<nav class="quick-links">
  {% for item in site.data.nav.main %}
  {% unless item.url contains "#" %}
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">
    {{ item.title }}
    </a>
    {% if forloop.last == false %} :: {% endif %}
  {% endunless%}
  {% endfor %}
</nav>
```